# Showing hyperlinks as plain text in a Richtextbox control

Tags: c#, winforms, hyperlink, richtextbox

Am using RichTextBox in a C#/Winforms application.

Am showing some text in this control which has got some UNC file paths embedded into  it:
for example:
filePath= "\\serverName\DirName\File"

Richtextbox shows this file path as a clickable hyperlink in the UI. 
filePath= "[\\serverName\DirName\File.doc](http://test)"

I want to show it as plain text instead.How do i achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's a property you can change named DetectUrls. It is set to `true` by default, set it to `false` to get rid of the clicking behaviour e.g.

```
richTextBoxName.DetectUrls = false;
```

Or you can simply set it to false using the properties editor in Visual Studio.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.detecturls.aspx